# laravel7 working image upload but ajax says there's error

Tags: ajax, laravel, file-upload, modal-dialog, laravel-7

So I'm doing an image upload via modal and ajax. It is working, it is saved in the database and saved in public folder as an image, except that the modal does not hide because there's something wrong as said in the console.

```
statusCode: ƒ ( map )
statusText: "OK"
```

[image: I don't know the error so, here's a screenshot]

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
//ADD PICTURE
    $('#btnUpload').click(function(){
        $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            data: new FormData($('#uploadForm').get(0)),
            url: "{{ route('gallery.store') }}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', 
            contentType: false,  // required for
            processData: false,  // jquery ajax file upload

            success: function(data){
                $successmessage = 'SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED';
                $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');
                $('#successmessage').text($successmessage);
            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $galleries=new Gallery;
        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('upload')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('upload')->storeAs('public/upload', $fileNameToStore);
            
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
        $galleries->description = $request->input('description');
        $galleries->upload = $fileNameToStore;
        $galleries->save();
    }
```

Comment: you are not returning anything in the store function, is there a reason for that, you can do something like, `if($galleries->save()){return true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `store` function, you have to return response status code. In the case of success, you return `200`.

```
return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
```

In the event of a failure, you return the code that corresponds to the error.

Example:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid'], 401);
```